# Bind configuration fails to lookup hostname but succeed with IP

Tags: dns

Going crazy here. This is a super simple bind setup which can reverse lookup but not resolve the IP of a name.

These are my (ridiculously) simple config files:

```
root@dns:/etc/bind/zones# cat db.192.168.1 
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA dns.mycompany.com. admin.mycompany.com. (
              3     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
      IN      NS      dns.mycompany.com.

; PTR Records
20   IN      PTR     dns.mycompany.com.         ; 192.168.1.20
149  IN      PTR     myharbor.mycompany.com.    ; 192.168.1.149




root@dns:/etc/bind/zones# cat db.mycompany.com 
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dns.mycompany.com. admin.mycompany.com. (
              3       ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      dns.mycompany.com.

; A records
dns.mycompany.com.            IN      A       192.168.1.20
myharbor.mycompany.com.       IN      A       192.168.1.149
```

If I do a lookup of the IP it works just fine:

```
root@dns:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup 192.168.1.149
Server:     192.168.1.20
Address:    192.168.1.20#53

149.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = myharbor.mycompany.com.
```

However if I lookup the name... it fails:

```
root@dns:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup myharbor.mycompany.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.1.20, trying next server
Server:     192.168.1.20
Address:    192.168.1.20#53

** server can't find myharbor.mycompany.com: SERVFAIL
```

I am sure it's something idiotic. Can I lend another pair of eyes here?

Thanks.

Comment: There was a typo in that I forgot to add the `.` after the A records. Fixed that but still doesn't work (same problem).

Comment: Voted to close, since it's both clearly off-topic for StackOverflow, as well as impossible to reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out in the end.

The culprit was in the `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file.

```
zone "mycompany.com" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/zones/db.mycompany.com"; # zone file path
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168.1";  # 10.128.0.0/16 subnet
};
```

There was a typo in the following line:

```
     file "/etc/bind/zones/db.mycompany.com"; # zone file path
```

It originally read:

```
     file "/etc/bind/zones/mycompany.com"; # zone file path
```

It just wouldn't be able to locate the file cause the path was typoed.

Phew!

Comment: Hmm. So this is something that nobody would have been able to "get" from your question. And since this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic for StackOverflow. Would you care to flag it for a move to a more appropriate site, or just close it?

Comment: Yes one couldn't figure it out because I wasn't thinking about typos in "other" files of my config. I was thinking about possible typos in the files I have pasted. I have seen other (very useful) "non dev" questions on this board and while this was peculiar to a specific typo I figured it would be good for this (and its solution) to be available to others for reference and how these different files cross reference each others.